# In SwiftUI how do I put the tabs in a TabbedView at the top of the view?

Tags: view, tabbed, swiftui

I have a view with tabs on the bottom, one of the `views` has `subviews`, to separate the logic visually, I put the tabs of the subview at the top of the view with the following code and it works perfectly:

```
self.tabbar.frame = CGRect( x: 0,
                            y: view.safeAreaInsets.top,
                            width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                            height: 50)
```

How do I do this in `SwiftUI`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to do this you could create your tabs view as a container of the individual tabs something like this...

```
struct TabbedView: View {

    @State private var selectedTab: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("First").tag(0)
                Text("Second").tag(1)
                Text("Third").tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            switch(selectedTab) {
                case 0: FirstTabView()
                case 1: SecondTabView()
                case 2: ThirdTabView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this, you are conditionally populating the "Tab page" based on the value of the segmented control.

By using `@State` and `$selectedTab` the segmented control will update the selectedTab value and then re-render the view which will replace the page based on the new value of `selectedTab`.

**Edit**

Switches now work in SwiftUI beta.

Comment: Unfortunately, at least in b1, we cannot use switch in ViewBuilders. `Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'`

Comment: @SteveRiggins thanks, that's a pain. Updated my answer for now though. Thanks

Comment: Control flow statements inside a `@ViewBuilder` block are not "conventional" - they get translated  by the compiler via `@_functionBuilder` structs, that enable the powerful SwiftUI DSL. `switch` won't work, as it is not part of the function builders [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md).

Comment: @Fogmeister, where did you get SegmentedControl from?

Comment: @NicoCobelo Perhaps from [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol). _"A horizontal control that consists of multiple segments, each segment functioning as a discrete button."_